# Voltage imbalance at the end of a sixty foot run

Tags: electrical

I have 240 volt service to my house.
I have a 50amp dual pole breaker feeding a sub panel 
60 feet away.
At the breaker I have 120 volts on each leg.
At the end of the sixty foot run, L1 has 100 volts, L2
Has 140 volts. This is measured under no loads, just the end of the wires.
I swapped the wires and the readings followed the 
Wire swap.
I’m thinking wiring issue. Does this sound right to everyone?

Update: Thanks everyone for the info. I picked up 100' of new copper, and bypassed the neutral in the circuit, that fixed the problem. So I'll be pulling it through conduit tomorrow... possible disaster averted!

Comment: are you measuring the voltage under load?

Comment: Which end did you swap the wires at?

Comment: At the breaker main panel in house, the suBpanel is 60 ft away for a storage building

Comment: This is measured under no loads, just at the end of the wire run

Comment: Are you sure there are no loads whatsoever in the shed?

Comment: I would check at the source and make sure it is not the feed from the breaker, with no load and good wire there should be no voltage drop without a load. The problem can be from a bad connection from the breaker to buss or a bad breaker. What brand/ type of panel is it there are several older brands that have this problem quite often the worst is FPE stablock (federal Pacific) the next worst is zinsco although I have seen less problems like this on zinsco but there have been some both are out of business, I have also seen this on top of the line panels that are still sold.

Comment: When they are not correct but do add up to 240V, that's a neutral problem. Go over your neutrals with a fine tooth comb.

Comment: Square D panels and breakers obviously.  Positive no load, other than the resistance of the wire.  It’s been working fine until Fourth of July eve. Power went out to shed.

Answer (score 2):

### It's an open neutral

This sort of voltage imbalance is symptomatic of one thing and one thing only -- an open neutral somewhere.  Fix the neutral issue, likely at a termination although it could be a damaged neutral on a direct bury cable or the likes, and the problem will go away.  Keep the shed turned off at the feeder breaker until then though, as open neutrals tend to be rather...incendiary to electrical equipment.